# SQL Server 2008 Express insertion delay appearing in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I have a system being build with SQL Server 2008 Express, running on an Atom processor machine, and I'm experiencing a strange problem.  The app uses Microsoft Entity Framework 4.0, and commits an insert using SaveChanges to store data in a table.

When I run my app on a desktop machine, the code runs fine, and the record appears in the table fairly quickly (in about 1 second), when viewing the table using Management Studio.  I have Select Top 1000 rows selected, and refreshing it finds the inserted row.

When I try the same thing on the Atom based processor, and I perform the same steps, it can often be 20-30 seconds before I am able to see the inserted record in the table.  Also, it appears that if I close the query window and open a new one, I am then able to see it.

Questions:

- Is there any type of caching results [with Express] which could be
  causing this problem?
- Is there any known performance issue like this known in any form?
- Any potential known issues running on an Atom processor?
- I *might* have the full SQL Server version of Management Studio on the machine (the machine may have previously had SQL Server 2008
  standard on it, which was uninstalled and then Express installed),
  with the standard installed Management Studio being run against the
  Express database.  Any gut feeling or known issues about this
  arrangement?  [I thought Management Studio for SQL 2008 and SQL 2008
  Express is the same, but not 100% sure].
- Is there any known reason with Express why closing a query window and then re-opening it would show the records when run re-running the
  same query would not?

**NOTE:** The table in question has only a handful of records in it (0 to 5 typically), so it isn't a table size issue.  It is a fairly small database, and there is plenty of memory available, disk space available, and the processor isn't heavily taxed during this operation.

Comment: Since it's Express, the database may be set to auto-close by default, have you checked if that setting is off? What operating system are you using? And more generally what are the differences (OS, MSSQL version and edition) between the two machines?